# RESTful API single or mass request

Tags: rest

I'm in the process of developing a `RESTful web service` to access a list of `Questions`, `Answers`, and `User_Responses` from an underlying `database`. I would also like to save new responses and edit previous responses VIA this web service, but before writing the code I would like to verify that I'm on the right track.

```
Question     : id, ...     
Answer       : id, question_id, ...     
User_Response: id, user_id, question_id, ...
```

**User_Response: user_id + question_id = unique**: This is somewhat complicated by rows in `User_Response` that have a null answer_id.

My thoughts on an implementation:
1. If `User_Response` has an answer in it and it was changed, submit an `Update request`.
2. If `User_Response` came up with a `null answer`, the developer will need to recognize this and set some sort of flag to use an update. Just like `#1`, on edit submit an `Update request`.
3. If `User_Response` came up with nothing for a given question, a flag is set alerting the program to send a `Create request on edit`.

**Is this too much to ask of external developers to do?**
**Rather than taking creates / updates on an individual basis, does it make more sense to do a mass assigning?** If this option, is it possible to insert and update on a per case basis with `SQL`?